# C programming - enum switch case with TCHAR

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement, tchar

I am doing a win32 program with C and I do not know how to do a enum and switch case with UNICODE.
I receive from the client a named pipe with this structure

```
    typedef struct {
TCHAR UtilOrigem[10];
TCHAR Comando[3]; // Comando
TCHAR Argumento1[10];
}cmd;
```

cmd.comando have values "00", "01", "02" .....

And I want to do a switch case with cmd.comando.

Please help me.
Thanks
Carlos

Comment: Have you tried `switch(cmd.comando[0]) { }`?

Comment: I realize you're working in C, not C#, but this might help... [http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch-enum](http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch-enum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int val = _ttoi(cmd.comando);
switch (val)
{
case 0:
   ...
   break;
case 1:
   ...
   break;
case 2:
   ...
   break;
...
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
int val = 10*(cmd.comando[0]-L'0')+(cmd.comando[1]-L'0');
switch (val)
{
case 0:
   ...
   break;
case 1:
   ...
   break;
case 2:
   ...
   break;
...
}
```

Comment: If `UNICODE` is defined as the question suggests, `'0'` will need to be `L'0'`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I agree, thanks (was indeed wondering about it after adding the second option).

Comment: @cacc: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it (if it solved your problem).

Comment: very grateful. It was the first time I put a question on this forum but now I consult a few years ago. @barakmanos

Comment: @cacc: No problem. The V is right next to the answer. If you click it, then it becomes green and I get 15 points.